# Is it possible to a create an Android game that uses the built in keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard

I know the keyboard is probably built into the Android OS and I have a simple game idea, sort of like a word game, but is it possible to create a game that uses this in the game itself?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is. I've only seen very few games implementing their own limited input buttons, but never a full keyboard. Based on the framework you're using this might be tricky to get it working, but overall, it shouldn't be a problem.